# testing if the absolute value of the mean is inferior to a threshold

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, p-value

I would like to test

$H_0:|\mu|\leq\tau$ vs $H_1:|\mu|>\tau$

where $\mu$ is the expected mean and $\tau>0$.

Do you know which test statistic I have to use ?

For instance, one can use the Wald statistic $\frac{\hat{\mu}-\mu}{\sigma}$ to test the nullity of $\mu$, but I think it is not adequate for this purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well the trick is to observe that to control type-I error control it is enough to calculate the null distribution under the two simple hypotheses $\mu = \tau$ and $\mu= - \tau$. Notice that in both cases you get that $|\mu|= \tau$. In other words under both these simple hypotheses you get the same distribution for the absolute value of $|\hat{\mu}|$.

Thus you can just calculate a two-sided p-value as follows:

$$ P = 2\int_{|\hat{\mu}|}^{\infty} \phi(x, \tau, \sigma^2) dx $$

Here $\phi(x, \tau, \sigma)$ is the density at $x$ of a normal distribution with mean $\tau$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

As per usual reject $P \leq \alpha$ to control type-I error rate at $\alpha$.